# Dataproc cluster creation fails with free Google Cloud credits

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using the free credits of Google Cloud. I followed [Dataproc tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/apache-spark-and-jupyter-notebooks-made-easy-with-dataproc-component-gateway-fa91d48d6a5a) but when I am running the following command I have an error regarding the storage capacity.

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --image-version=1.5 \
  --master-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
  --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
  --bucket=${BUCKET_NAME} \
  --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
  --enable-component-gateway \
  --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-storage' \
  --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/pip-install.sh
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I changed `n1-standard-4` to `n1-standard-1` but I could not fix it. However, when I removed `--image-version=1.5` the command works. Does it create any problem for the rest of the program?

Also from the web interface when I click on JupyterLab link, I can not see Python 3 icon among the kernels available on my Dataproc cluster. I only have Python 2 and it keeps saying connection with the server is gone.

Here is picture of JupyterLab error: [image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing an error regarding storage capacity because in 1.5 image version Dataproc uses bigger 1000 GiB disks for master and worker nodes to improve performance. You can reduce disk size by using `--master-boot-disk-size=100GB` and `--worker-boot-disk-size=100GB` command flags:

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --image-version=1.5 \
  --master-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
  --master-boot-disk-size=100GB \
  --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
  --worker-boot-disk-size=100GB \
  --bucket=${BUCKET_NAME} \
  --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
  --enable-component-gateway \
  --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-storage' \
  --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/pip-install.sh
```

When you removed `--image-version=1.5` flag this command used default 1.3 image version that does not support Python 3 by default, that's why you are not seeing Python 3 kernel in JupyterLab.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. I tried your suggestion and I got the following error:Waiting for cluster creation operation...⠛
WARNING: For PD-Standard without local SSDs, we strongly recommend provisioning 1TB or larger to ensure consistently high I/O performance. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/d
ocs/disks/performance for information on disk I/O performance.
Waiting for cluster creation operation...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation [projects/--/--/--] failed: Timeout waiting for instance m
ysamc3-m to report in..

Comment: Just to give an update. I solved the issue by creating a single node cluster. now I have access to both jupyterlab and notebook 3. I also could run the tutorial successfully. The only question that I have is : The tutorial says the code will be run by Python 3 kernel (not the PySpark kernel). Is that the reason for taking so long to get the result of the query back from big-query to Jupyter notebook?  how can I increase the speed of running the queries by this method?

Comment: To increase query execution speed you usually need to increase cluster size, especially if you are using a single-node cluster. You can try to use 2-worker cluster with `e2-standard-2` machine type for master and worker nodes - maybe it will fit in free credits with 100 GiB boot disks.